# Does Elder brother have ownership of his younger brothers?

Tags: mahabharata

Yudhistira betted his brother in game of dice. Does the elder brother have absolute ownership of his younger brothers ? Or Yudhistira betted because the brothers(Bhim, Arjun etc) accepted Yudhistira's ownership due to respect towards him (Yudhistir)

Comment: Yes, elder brother is like father and has rights.

Comment: @Kanthri Source ?